# Javascript: unable to execute init function

Tags: javascript, jquery, groupdocs

I am working on a groupdocs viewer, and want to re-create plug-in like that,

groupdocs code below

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            debugger
            var defaults = {

            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
    }
    $.fn.viewer = function (method) {
        console.log(method)
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.viewer');
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

this code is working fine but when I create my custom code like below,

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            debugger
            var defaults = {

            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
    }
    $.fn.secondFunction = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
           return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
       } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
           return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
       } else {
           $.error('Method' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.viewer');
       }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

`secondFunction` and event init: is not executing,

what might be the problem with my code

Comment: You're never calling `secondFunction` in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working just fine. Open the inspector and run press the run button below, and you will see that it pauses on the debugger statement.

```js
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            debugger
            var defaults = {

            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
    }
    $.fn.secondFunction = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
           return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
       } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
           return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
       } else {
           $.error('Method' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.viewer');
       }
    };
}(jQuery));

$().secondFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```